# How to change the output of bcp package in R so that i can save it to a txt file

Tags: r, file, save, output

I just got my output from bcp package, but it is of a "bcp" class and cannot be saved to a file using `write.table` function, i need to change the class to data.frame type or try some other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects of class 'bcp' are an R list. The best way to store them is:

```
save(objname, file="bcpobjt.Rdta")
```

If you need an ASCII representation that can still be interpreted as the full R object, use `dput` or `dump`.

If you want the screen output then use either `sink` or `capture.output`:

```
 capture.output(print(objname), file="myoutfil.txt")
```

Or:

```
 sink("myoutfil.txt")
 print(objname)
 sink()
```

Comment: Thanks, but what i exactly want is a txt file which contains the output with the same format as the one in the console, is that possible to achieve?